# live text streaming in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios6, http-live-streaming

I want to display live text in my app.And i want it live without breaking & continue with my app.

For Example,
 If someone write "Hello" then i get "Hello" from server.Now suppose they type "Good Morning" then i get only "Good Morning" in response.Whatever is next type that only i want.

I want to call only one webservice and from that i want to get live data. What should be logic at iphone side for this.

I search a lot for text live streaming but i only get HLS.

I have read apple document but I don't understand how to use it.

Is there any other solution? or any other logic?

Comment: i think you want to create application like iMob or like chat application, right??

Comment: no i want like someone whatever typing that directly shown on my app.There is no submit option to submit data.In chat we do enter to submit data.

Answer (score 1):

see this tutorial..

[how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

Many iOS apps use HTTP to communicate to a web server, because it’s easy, convenient, and well-supported. In above tutorial you see the code and also Demo about it..

hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), they are very useful for this type of thing. Also, [Pusher](http://pusher.com) is a fairly easy to get started with web socket service.

Answer (score 0):

Following link for "Tutorial: How To Build An iOS Chat App Using Cocoa Classes" 
Like Chat application Source code and php code is available in below link

```
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html
```